# Display Powertip tooltip won't display over lack of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have Powertips in DataTables in JQuery UI tabs.
I have the tooltip set to follow mouse (so I can only change position with margin). The tooltip will only display over existing content, if there is nothing below the table the tooltip will be higher to fit over existing content.

The position for the tooltip has to be set to absolute or it doesn't work correctly.

Changing positions or margins wouldn't work because the results would be different depending upon the number of entries in the table. I tried changing the UI Tabs position to relative but that doesn't work. I don't think it's a positioning problem with the div boxes because it can appear outside the div, just not where no content is.

I'm not having a problem with z-index, the tooltip gets moved up so it can fit on top of existing content.

Here is the layout I have

```
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<table id="table_id" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="column-icon">Headers</th>...</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" class="tooltips icon-small 1"><img src="icon.png" width="40" /></a></td>
        <td id="row-name"><a href="" class="tooltips 1">Name</a></td>
        <td>Content</td>...</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>tab two content.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I don't have much set for the standard div elements for the Tabs. I tried adding position:relative; but it had no effect.

```
#tabs {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color:#242424;
    width:1200px;
    padding-bottom:37px;
}
```

the class tooltips is using this javascript

```
$('.tooltips').powerTip({
    followMouse: true,
});
```

and the class 1 is the powertip tooltip content. icon-small is just a class for some css hover overlay

The only time I get the desired effect is when I add a lot of content (in this case, breaks) at the end outside of any elements.

I am using the latest JQuery, JQuery UI, JQuery DataTables, and JQuery Powertips.

Comment: Show us your code. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Use Position Relative in your Container and position absolute in the next one.

Comment: I want to share the code but there's way too much of it. I'll see if I can simplify it if I can't find where to set position relative.

Comment: Ok I changed some code and did some things and it's not the div box being a problem. If there isn't any content after the datatables/ui tabs then the tooltip won't extend, but I threw in a ton of <br /> after and the tooltip is working fine. I added position:relative; to the tabs div box (uppermost parent) and it does not work. I'll edit first post in a second to include code